# Griffon Compilation error: cannot override firePropertyChange?

Tags: compilation, upgrade, griffon

Upgrading my 0.3.1 Griffon app into 0.9.4 found the following compilation error:

```
 [griffonc] Threading injection feature disabled.

 [griffonc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

 [griffonc] ..\sgmentia-client\griffon\app\models\com\nortia\sgmentia\client\maestros\MaestrosModel.groovy: -1: firePropertyChange(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in com.nortia.sgmentia.client.maestros.MaestrosModel cannot override firePropertyChange in com.nortia.sgmentia.client.maestros.MaestrosModelSupport; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
 [griffonc]  @ line -1, column -1.
 [griffonc] 1 error
 Compilation error: Compilation Failed
```

There are **no mention** of  **firePropertyChange** in my code so I dont know how to go on.

The referred classes look like follows:

```
abstract class MaestrosModelSupport
...
class MaestrosModel extends MaestrosModelSupport
```

Ideas??

---

### Update

I've followed the naming convention (every Model must end up with XXXModel) and now the project compiles.

However after some refactoring there is something new:

```
 [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\maestro\desarrollo\projects\interactionManager\sgmentia-client\staging
 ERROR [main]: [1] ApplicationDefaultExceptionHandler Se ha producido un error inesperado en la aplicaci¾n: Interfaces must have java.lang.Object as superclass in class file com/nortia/sgmentia/client/DocumentController

 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Interfaces must have java.lang.Object as superclass in class file com/nortia/sgmentia/client/DocumentController
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
```

So what now?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be another instance of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-440
I wonder how are you setting up your codebase, for example, why are the models placed in `sgmentia-client\griffon\app\models`instead of `sgmentia-client\griffon-app\models`.

You can have abstract model classes as bases classes for all models, that should be supported form the get go, as long as you follow the conventions

```
abstract class AbstractSupportModel { ... }
class MaestrosModel extends AbstractSupportModel { ... }
```

Both `AbstractSupportModel` and `MaestrosModel` are placed in `sgmentia-client\griffon-app\models`.

Comment: Hi Andres, 
I'm afraid that is not the answer, :(.

The path issue was just a copy&paste mistake, the code is placed in the right place .."griffon-app\models".
I've tried also to disable most of AST Injection features doing the following compilation:

griffon -Dgriffon.disable.ast.injection=true -Dgriffon.disable.threading.injection=true compile

It finally compiles! Now I'm trying if everything is ok at runtime.

Anyway I still think there is something wrong with AST injection and these weird compilation messages, but dont know exactly what it is.

Thanks, 
Ivan.